# Gravity increases drastically when walking off edge when comparted to jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void UpdateMovement()
    {
        Vector2 targetDir = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        targetDir.Normalize();

        currentDir = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentDir, targetDir, ref currentDirVelocity, moveSmoothTime);

        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            velocityY = -gravity;
        }

        // jump
        if (controller.isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            velocityY = jumpForce;
        }
        // sprint
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            velocity = (transform.forward * currentDir.y + transform.right * currentDir.x) * sprintSpeed + Vector3.up * velocityY;
        }
        else
        {
            velocity = (transform.forward * currentDir.y + transform.right * currentDir.x) * walkSpeed + Vector3.up * velocityY;
        }

        velocityY -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log(velocityY);

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

This is the code that I am using to move and jump in my game. Those functions work fine, the problem is in the gravity when walking off a surface. When jumping gravity works as intended but when falling without jumping (walking off the edge) gravity is still set to it's default value (15) so the characters falls incredibly fast.

I understand that this is caused by having no function to change this value when falling from an edge but I have found no way of making this happen without breaking all of the vertical movement.

Comment: Well it looks like you are manually adding gravity and assuming gravity gives you a fixed permanent speed increase.  Why not just let unity physics do the work

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the gravity as Brackeys did in his [FPS Controller Tutorial](https://youtu.be/_QajrabyTJc?t=914):

```cs
if (isGrounded) {
    velocityY = -2f;
}
```